# cy.add is not a function

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

After my cytoscape obj is created (I'm using the 'ready' callback) I do an ajax query to get a list of nodes then try to add them. However, I get the error 'cy.add is not a function'. What am I missing?

On document ready:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: $('#cy'),

    ready: function() {
      debugger;
      refreshNodes();
    },
...
```

In refreshNodes():

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(data, s, jqXHR) {
     data.forEach(function(cv, i, ary) {
         cy.add(...);
     } 
});
```

When I set a breakpoint in ready and dump out cy it looks like this in chrome dev tools:

```
<div id="cy" class="left" style="height: 822.22px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);">...</div>
```

Version is 2.7.4.

Comment: It looks like you're assigning the actual DOM element to `cy` at some point or you're trying to access your declared `cy` variable in a scope that it doesn't exist. Some browsers automatically creates variable bindings for elements with IDs. Try changing the `div` ID to something other than `cy` and see what happens.

Comment: Well that's mildly embarrassing. Lets never speak of this again. ;) Thanks.

Comment: The ready callback is necessary for only very particular usecases.  Most people will never need it.  In your case, I think `ready()` is called before `cy` is assigned in your upper scope.  It's usually better to just call `cytoscape()` and do whatever you need on the next line.  Also note Cytoscape supports promises for `elements` and `style`, so you can just pass `elements: $.ajax(...)`, and Cytoscape will add the elements when the promise resolves.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'll try that (re: elements). I tried using ready() after reading a post you wrote elsewhere, but yeah-- you werent talking about cy.add(). Is there an example somewhere of elements: $.ajax(...)?

Comment: This is note is for those who come after-- using cy.add(...) to add your nodes after cytoscape() isnt recommended unless you know everything (e.g. their positions). ..looking into the other option (elements promise).

Comment: More recent versions allow nodes with null positions to be drawn.  By default, they are placed at (0, 0).